# QGIS Find position for point objects on a line object and add this length attribute to any point object

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, linear-referencing, position

My QGIS (3.22. Biatowieza) question is the following:
I have a line layer with objects that have a length in metres. And there is a separate point layer with point objects that are located besides of the line geometry, not directly on it.

Finally, the point objects should get a position attribute corresponding to the belonging length of the line (possibly with rectangle transformation as the nearest distance between line and point object).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, Please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Questions should always answer the questions "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" then ask a question (with a question mark). Please [Edit] your Question to meet this criteria.

Comment: I can't understand what is unclear about this question, or has this been edited? Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

On the point layer, you can get the length of the nearest line with this expression (e.g. with Field calculator to create a new attribute):

```
overlay_nearest(
    'line',  -- replace with the name of your line layer
    $length
)[0]
```